# Best way to retrieve form data from a nested component in an Angular project

Tags: angular

I'm working on an angular project that has the following situation: there is one component (ClientViewComponent) that contains:

- A summary of the whole client form in the form of labels (ClientOverviewComponent);
- Different "sub-forms" through which the user can switch between for edit (for simplicty, let's focus on only one, called ClientGeneralComponent);

Only one of these sub-forms is displayed at a time for edit, but the overview displays the values of all the inputs in the sub-forms, in real time.

So this is what exists now (simplified to only show parts of interest):

**ClientViewComponent HTML**

```html
    <div class="container overview-container">
      <h2>Client Overview</h2>
      <client-overview
        [data]="clientOverviewData" 
        [generalGroup]="clientForm.controls['generalGroup']"
        (editFrame)="editFrame($event)">
      </client-overview>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="(currentFrame$ | async)" class="container part-container">
      <h2>Please choose: </h2>  
      <client-general 
        *ngIf="(currentFrame$ | async).code === 'general'" [data]="clientGeneralData" [formGroup]="clientForm.controls['generalGroup']">
      </client-general>
    </div>
```

**ClientViewComponent TS**

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.clientForm = this.fb.group({
            generalGroup: this.fb.group({
                name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(256)]], 
                code: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(32)]], 
                addressGroup: this.fb.group({
                    address: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(512)]],
                    address2: ['', [Validators.maxLength(512)]],
                    city: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(256)]],
                    state: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(64)]],
                    zipCode: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(64)]],
                    country: ['', [Validators.required]],
                })                
            })
        });
}
```

**ClientOverviewHTML**

```html
<div class="span-container">
            <span [ngClass]="{ 'modified-value' : !isNew && generalGroup.controls['name'].dirty }">* Client Name: {{generalGroup.controls['name'].value}}</span>
            <span [ngClass]="{ 'modified-value' : !isNew && generalGroup.controls['code'].dirty }">* Client Code: {{generalGroup.controls['code'].value}}</span>
            <span [ngClass]="{ 'modified-value' : !isNew && addressGroup.controls['address'].dirty }">* Address: {{addressGroup.controls['address'].value}}</span>        
            <span [ngClass]="{ 'modified-value' : !isNew && addressGroup.controls['address2'].dirty }">Address #2: {{addressGroup.controls['address2'].value}}</span>        
            <span [ngClass]="{ 'modified-value' : !isNew && addressGroup.controls['city'].dirty }">* City: {{addressGroup.controls['city'].value}}</span>        
            <span [ngClass]="{ 'modified-value' : !isNew && addressGroup.controls['state'].dirty }">* State: {{addressGroup.controls['state'].value}}</span>        
            <span [ngClass]="{ 'modified-value' : !isNew && addressGroup.controls['country'].dirty }">* Country: {{country}}</span>        
            <span [ngClass]="{ 'modified-value' : !isNew && addressGroup.controls['zipCode'].dirty }">* Zip Code: {{addressGroup.controls['zipCode'].value}}</span>            
</div>
```

**ClientOverviewComponent TS**

```js
export class ClientOverviewComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input('data')
    set Data(value: ClientOverviewData) {
        this.setData(value);
    }

    generalGroup: FormGroup;
    addressGroup: FormGroup;
    @Input('generalGroup') 
    set GeneralGroup(value: FormGroup) {
        this.generalGroup = value;
        this.addressGroup = value.get('addressGroup') as FormGroup;
        this.refreshClientValues();                
}
```

*The ClientGeneralComponent HTML is just a regular form with a formGroup and inputs with the corresponding formControlName*

**ClientGeneralComponent TS**

```js
export class ClientGeneralComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input('data')
    set Data(value: ClientGeneralData) {
        this.setData(value);
    }

    formGroup: FormGroup;
    addressGroup: FormGroup;
    @Input('formGroup') 
    set FormGroup(value: FormGroup){
        this.formGroup = value;
        this.addressGroup = value.get('addressGroup') as FormGroup;
}
```

Now, all this works fine. The complete form works as intended, the user fills in the inputs for the General component and the values are shown in the overview, in real time. The question rose when I started doing unit tests for the components. The problem is that, for the test class for the ClientGeneralComponent, I have to declare the form groups and controls again, the same way it's done in the ClientViewComponent code. My idea was that, if I could move the General form initialization from the ClientViewComponent to the ClientGeneralComponent (which actually contains the controls), there would be no need to copy the form init code in the test class, like this:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ClientGeneralComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        component.formGroup = fb.group({
            name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(256)]],
            code: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(32)]],
            addressGroup: fb.group({
                address: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(512)]],
                address2: ['', [Validators.maxLength(512)]],
                city: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(256)]],
                state: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(64)]],
                zipCode: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(64)]],
                country: ['', [Validators.required]]
            })
        });
        fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

But if I move the general form init code to the child form, I start getting "cannot read property of undefined" errors in the Overview component, since it didn't initialize the "generalGroup" property and its controls. So my question is if there is a way to do that, to initialize the form group in the child component where it belongs, and still be able to bind it in the parent form.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: move the General form initialization from the ClientViewComponent to the ClientGeneralComponent. ClientGeneralComponent will expose (@Output) form change observable. The parent ClientViewComponent will subscribe to this form change observable to get the generalGroup object. This generalGroup object can then be sent as input to ClientOverviewComponent for display.

Comment: @NithinKumarBiliya could you elaborate more, with a short code example, please? I'm very new to Angular so I'm still a little lost...

Comment: can you reproduce this scenario on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)? It will be easier to modify that to work for your scenario

Comment: @NithinKumarBiliya ok finished making a reproduction. Here's the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2av8po

So the idea is how to move the general form init currently on client-view.component to client-general.component, while keeping the binding in overview functional.

Comment: This may be a use case for [ngx-sub-form](https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form) which is based on the ControlValueAccessor interface. In general, I think it's a bad idea to pass FormGroup - it's better to patchValue. Using good practices of container-presentation, separation of concerns, using typescript models, gets you to the following https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-81fq7s. If you need more from the form such as dirty, validity, touched etc. extend the model and emit this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the working code on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pwmd9d).

It is implemented a bit different from what I had explained in the comment.

The ClientForm is inside the ClientGeneralComponent. On the form.valueChange, it emits the new client object. This is picked up by the parent ClientViewComponent and sent to the other ClientOverviewComponent. Angular change detection takes care of updating the values in all the components.

**client-general.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, of, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { startWith, map, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { IClient } from './client';

@Component({
    selector: 'client-general',
    templateUrl: './client-general.component.html'
})
export class ClientGeneralComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  clientForm: FormGroup;

  @Output()
  clientObj: EventEmitter<IClient>;

  destroy$: Subject<boolean>;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.destroy$ = new Subject<boolean>();
    this.clientObj = new EventEmitter<IClient>();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.clientForm = this.fb.group({
      generalGroup: this.fb.group({
                name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(256)]]
      })
    });

    this.clientForm.valueChanges
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe(() => this.clientObj.emit(this.clientForm.getRawValue()));
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next(true);
    this.destroy$.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

**client-general.component.html**

```
<div [formGroup]="clientForm.controls['generalGroup']">
    <h3>General</h3>
    <div>
        <span>Client Name</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" formControlName="name"/>    
    </div>
</div>
```

**client-view.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { IClient } from './client';

@Component({
  selector: 'client-view',
  templateUrl: './client-view.component.html'
})
export class ClientViewComponent implements OnInit  {

  clientObj: IClient;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**client-view.component.html**

```
<div>
  <h2>Client Overview</h2>
  <client-overview
  [clientObj]="clientObj"></client-overview>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>Please choose: </h2>  
  <client-general (clientObj)="clientObj=$event"></client-general>
</div>
```

**client-overview.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { IClient } from './client';

@Component({
    selector: 'client-overview',
    templateUrl: './client-overview.component.html'
})
export class ClientOverviewComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input()
    clientObj: IClient;

    ngOnInit() {        

    }
}
```

**client-overview.component.html**

```
<div>
    <div>            
        <h3>General</h3>
        <div>
            <span>Name: {{clientObj?.generalGroup.name}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```